# Domain Controller, git and dotnet CLI

Tags: windows-server-2019

Are there are known issues, or concerns, with installing the git and dotnet CLI on a domain controller?

I intend to run a dotnet project on my DCs but want to avoid opening them up to build/release pipelines and don't want to deploy builds from a local machine. Instead the plan is to host a repo on the DCs and build the project using the dotnet CLI

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid it for I/O and security reasons.  But honestly, it should be possible -- assuming you're DCs aren't already overloaded with authentication requests and auditing events.  Is spinning-up a virtual build server out of the question?

Comment: > Is spinning-up a virtual build server out of the question?

At the moment, yeah. However it is something I may do in the future (when I have the resources :P ).

> Personally, I'd avoid it for I/O and security reasons. But honestly, it should be possible

The potential security hole was the only thing which occurred to me but it sounds like installing them wont interfere with any DC processes.
Thank you :)